# Converting Boolean array (i.e True False) into actual values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

I am trying to convert all true values in array 'v' to their actual numbers. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import load

dict_data = load('E_starData.npz')
EStar = dict_data['arr_0']
v = np.greater(EStar, 0.1)
print(v) #prints an array of true and false values, would like to display true values as the actual number
```

The code is pulling a saved zip file with all the data.

Comment: Can add a sample of your input ?

Comment: @MarkMeyer This will only include the non-zero values in a flat array and not `EStar`'s shape.

Comment: Your right @Ehsan — it's not clear to me what the other values should be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
v = EStar * (EStar>0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways to approach the problem from the start, but building off of your code:

```py
print([val for bool, val in zip(v, Estar) if bool])
```